# Simple versioning (in PHP/Zend Framework)?

Tags: php, zend-framework, versioning

i am wondering how can i have simple versioning, say i want to be able to undo past edits (just up to 3 will do) to a post. maybe because the app allows other user to edit a post. but i may want the owner to restore the post for example.

do i just store the full post in another field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this previously by creating a table which contains the following columns:
id, serialisation value of entire row you want backed up, the table it is for, datetime, why the backup was created.

That way you have a complete listing of all the versions of that table. I use Doctrine ORM so that way I can setup a postSave hook to create a new backup version in that table.

Comment: `postUpdate` in doctrine 2 :)

Answer (score 3):

One suggestion could be something like this:

you propably have each post as a separate row in the table and it has indexes that point to right threat and you retain their order by those indexes.

Add a "revision" to each post row. Everytime user edits the post, you store a new row into table but with higher revision. And when showing the posts, you just fetch the one with highest revision..

Comment: this is one way, then i guess i also can setup a automated job to clear old revisions

Answer (score 0):

Doctrine Versionable Bebaviour may be the simplest solution for you:

[Doctrine - Doctrine ORM for PHP - Versionable](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/behaviors%3Acore-behaviors%3Aversionable/en)